# Add Static Page to Reading Settings for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post types and I want to let the user choose the static page for the archive page. For example, under Post page. I would like to add a Projects page: [   Dropdown ]

Is there a way to add another static page option to the reading settings page? Is there an existing hook to modify it?

[image: reading settings]

Also, is there a way to mark the selected page like this in Pages?

[image]

**Update:**

Looking at `/wp/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1768`

```
/**
 * Filters the default post display states used in the posts list table.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 * @since 3.6.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
 *
 * @param array   $post_states An array of post display states.
 * @param WP_Post $post        The current post object.
 */
$post_states = apply_filters( 'display_post_states', $post_states, $post );

if ( ! empty($post_states) ) {
    $state_count = count($post_states);
    $i = 0;
    echo ' &mdash; ';
    foreach ( $post_states as $state ) {
        ++$i;
        ( $i == $state_count ) ? $sep = '' : $sep = ', ';
        echo "<span class='post-state'>$state$sep</span>";
    }
}
```

It seems like there are hooks for the post_state, but how do you set it?

Also, looking at `/wp-admin/options-reading.php:83`

Is there a way to modify the Reading setting without actually modifying the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to add another static page option to the reading
>   settings page?

Yes.

Code:

```
/**
 * Adds a custom field: "Projects page"; on the "Settings > Reading" page.
 */
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    $id = 'page_for_projects';
    // add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section = 'default', $args = array() )
    add_settings_field( $id, 'Projects page:', 'settings_field_page_for_projects', 'reading', 'default', array(
        'label_for' => 'field-' . $id, // A unique ID for the field. Optional.
        'class'     => 'row-' . $id,   // A unique class for the TR. Optional.
    ) );
} );

/**
 * Renders the custom "Projects page" field.
 *
 * @param array $args
 */
function settings_field_page_for_projects( $args ) {
    $id = 'page_for_projects';
    wp_dropdown_pages( array(
        'name'              => $id,
        'show_option_none'  => '&mdash; Select &mdash;',
        'option_none_value' => '0',
        'selected'          => get_option( $id ),
    ) );
}

/**
 * Adds page_for_projects to the white-listed options, which are automatically
 * updated by WordPress.
 *
 * @param array $options
 */
add_filter( 'whitelist_options', function ( $options ) {
    $options['reading'][] = 'page_for_projects';

    return $options;
} );
```

Preview:

[image]

> Also, is there a way to mark the selected page like this in Pages?

Yes.

Code:

```
/**
 * Filters the post states on the "Pages" edit page. Displays "Projects Page"
 * after the post/page title, if the current page is the Projects static page.
 *
 * @param array $states
 * @param WP_Post $post
 */
add_filter( 'display_post_states', function ( $states, $post ) {
    if ( intval( get_option( 'page_for_projects' ) ) === $post->ID ) {
        $states['page_for_projects'] = __( 'Projects Page' );
    }

    return $states;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Preview:

[image]

And if you must or need to, you can use JavaScript/jQuery to move the "*Projects page*" field to *below* the "*Posts page*" in the "*Your homepage displays*" column.

Comment: What should the template file to be used by Projects Page be called?

Comment: @Sheedo It's up to *you* on what name you want to give the template.